# Displaying Alphabets vertically (Skipping)

Tags: assembly, tasm

I would like to ask how can I print the uppercase letters like this: 
A
C
.
.
Z

I have my codes.

```
.model small
.code
.stack 100
org 100h 
start:
      mov  ah, 02h
      mov   cl, 41h 
skip:
     mov  dl, cl
     Int 21h 
     inc    cl
     cmp  cl, 5Bh
     jnz   skip
     Int    27h
end start
```

Comment: What is your question?  Does that code not do what you want?  If you just want to increment by two, just `add cl, 2` instead of `inc cl`

Comment: Peter Cordes: Uhm it prints only uppercase letters from A to Z vertically, but the program that i need is to print uppercase letters by skipping it i.e ACEG and so on. I don't know how:(

Comment: Read the second sentence of my last comment.

Comment: Peter Cordes: Oh I knew now, what is the problem in my codes. thank you for sharing some useful codes and for helping also :)